# Editing outlook distribution list using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, outlook, distribution-list

Anyone has any idea about how to edit the outlook distribution list using python?
I tried SMTP and IMAP lib in python but basically it can send and receive the emails from an excel 
I need to get member from Excel and update it to outlook DL.

Comment: giving this error when i use contacts = address_lists['Global Address List'] pywintypes.com_error: (-2147467260, 'Operation aborted', None, None)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can access "**Distribution List"** from win32com

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
address_lists = outlook.AddressLists
dls = address_lists['All Distribution Lists']
```

Comment: Do you know I can iterate that list?

Answer (score -1):

You can to use with win32com.client package and control to your Outlook application, for example:

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
address_lists = outlook.AddressLists
contacts = address_lists['Global Address List']
contacts.AddressEntries.Add()  # to add contact TODO

first = contacts.AddressEntries.GetFirst()
first.Update()  # to update contact TODO
first.Delete()  # to delete contact
```

see also [outlook AddressEntries doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.addressentries_methods.aspx) and [outlook AddressEntry doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.addressentry_members.aspx)

Comment: it does not give "Distribution List" rather global address list.